# When does Max=Sup ?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I know the following statement is true.

$\forall S,$ (S is compact and S$\neq\emptyset \to \max(S)=\sup(S))$

In what else situations can be Max=Sup ?

Comment: When $\sup(S) \in S$.

Comment: Oh.. so simple.. Thanks so much.